# Unable to get attribute value from xml tag

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I am new to AJAX and XML.

I have the following XML:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<auth>
<token>123-123</token>
<perms>read</perms>
<user nsid="id" username="user_name" fullname="Full Name"/>
</auth>
</rsp>
```

I have the following code:

```
 function readXML(xml)
    {
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user");
        document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= x.getAttribute("username"));
window.location.replace("path/info.php?username="+ x.getAttribute("username"));
    }

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200)
        {
            readXML(xhttp)
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", <?php echo ($url);?>, true);
    xhttp.send();
```

I am unable to get any attribute(nsid, username, fullname) of `<user>` xml tag. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a closing parentheses `)` too much at the end of this line:

```
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= x.getAttribute("username"));
```

Update these two lines:

```
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= x.getAttribute("username"));
window.location.replace("path/info.php?username="+ x.getAttribute("username"));
```

To

```
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= x[0].getAttribute("username");
window.location.replace("path/info.php?username="+ x[0].getAttribute("username"));
```

`x` is now `x[0]` because [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) in  `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user")` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and you want the first item from this collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("FileName.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xml->user['nsid'];
$xml->user['username'];
$xml->user['fullname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library for ajax/xml processing in JavaScript. The most popular library is [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (which is really powerful, so take a look at it!).

An easy example using jQuery can look like: ([sample os jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zejmgh6p/))

```
// Callback for processing the response from the server
var callback = function (data) { 
    var token = data.getElementsByTagName("token");
    var tokenValue = token[0].innerHTML;


    var user = data.getElementsByTagName("user");
    var usernameAttributeValue = user[0].getAttribute("username");
};

// Actually calls the server, ajax endpoint, and calls callback on response
$.ajax(ajaxEndpointUrl).done(callback);
```